# call .document.getElementByName when no ie object is launched

Tags: vba, excel

I want to launch a browser and click an element that is not accessible through the Tab so I can't SendKeys.  If it were on internet explorer I would try to use the ie.document.getElementByName function but that is not an option because I launched Google Chrome through a shell function (see code below for Chrome launch methodology).  Is there a way to still access html elements when there is no object for .document.getElementByName to invoke?

```
Dim chromePath As String
chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
Shell (chromePath & " -url https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/Report/Sales/Sales/Generate?reportID=undefined")
```

Comment: You'd have a similar problem if you `Shell`'d your IE instance, you know.

Comment: Look into [Selenium](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168959/23788)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy if you do the launch via selenium. Much harder if not impossible (haven't yet found a vba method) to attach to an existing browser instance e.g. one launched from command line that is different from that used by the current WebDriver instance.

I am gonna go out on a limb and say that because your commandline stuff is done via `Shell`, and is only to launch Chrome, then you can simply replace with installing [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic), adding a reference to `selenium type library` and then using selenium to open Chrome as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub OpenChromeAndSelect()
'References to Selenium type library
    Dim d As WebDriver, el As WebElement
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/Report/Sales/Sales/Generate?reportID=undefined"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        Set el = .FindElementById("myID")
        'Do other stuff
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like the best solution.  Now I just have to figure out how to use Selenium lol.  Already posted a question trying to figure it out.